# Flutter: como reconstruir un widget totalmente cuando redibujo el widget padre

Tags: webservice, flutter, gridview

Tengo un gridview donde muestro un listado de productos cargados desde un api, el grid cuando necesita mas elementos por el usuario dar scroll hacia debajo pide mas elementos al api y los dibuja y asi sucesivamente.

Mi problema radica en que si ejecuto un setState() en el widget padre su hijo(el gridview)  se redibuja pero no elimina los elementos que ya cargo del api y tampoco mueve el index del gridview al inicio, lo cual impide que si cambio algun parametro de la busqueda de los elementos al api, no comience a buscarlos con esos nuevos parametros a menos que llegue a un punto en el scroll donde este pidiendo mas elementos que los que ya tengo guardados.

Implemente una solucion de pasarle un parametro booleano si deseo que se reinicie completamente, de ser true muevo con un ScrollController el index del gridview al inicio y limpio completamente la lista de elementos que ya se habian cargado del api, de esa forma funciona, lo hace bien, pero me gustaria escuchar variantes mas profesionales o no de como solucionar este problema, gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: hola te recomiendo mi canal donde estoy subiendo contenido para hacer animaciones : https://youtube.com/diegoveloper